# spinner within expandable list view? in the child menu

Tags: android

I'm having an issue trying to do this while setting in the childView.  this is how i am trying to do now..on clicking on any spinner item i am getting a bad token exception..Unable to add window..token null is not for a window...can someone tell me wats wrong >???

```
public class Form extends ExpandableListActivity{
ExpandableListAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.form);
    // Set up our adapter
    mAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter();
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    registerForContextMenu(getExpandableListView());
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Sample menu");
   // menu.add(0, 0, 0, R.string.expandable_list_sample_action);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    ExpandableListContextMenuInfo info = (ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    String title = ((TextView) info.targetView).getText().toString();

    int type = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(info.packedPosition);
    if (type == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {
        int groupPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(info.packedPosition); 
        int childPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(info.packedPosition); 
        Toast.makeText(this, title + ": Child " + childPos + " clicked in group " + groupPos,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    } else if (type == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_GROUP) {
        int groupPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(info.packedPosition); 
        Toast.makeText(this, title + ": Group " + groupPos + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * A simple adapter which maintains an ArrayList of photo resource Ids. 
 * Each photo is displayed as an image. This adapter supports clearing the
 * list of photos and adding a new photo.
 *
 */
public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    // Sample data set.  children[i] contains the children (String[]) for groups[i].
    private String[] groups = { "Temperature", "Water flow", "Power usage", "Recent errors" };
    private String[][] children = {
            { "Temp1", "Temp2", "Temp3", "Temp4" },
            { "Water", "Water", "Water", "Water" },
            { "Uage", "usage" },
            { "Error1", "Error2" }
    };
    private String[] contents = {
            "Dwight D. Eisenhower",
            "John F. Kennedy",
            "Lyndon B. Johnson",
            "Richard Nixon",
            "Gerald Ford",
            "Jimmy Carter",
            "Ronald Reagan",
            "George H. W. Bush",
            "Bill Clinton",
            "George W. Bush",
            "Barack Obama"
    };


    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return children[groupPosition][childPosition];
    }

    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return children[groupPosition].length;
    }

    public TextView getGenericView() {
        // Layout parameters for the ExpandableListView
        AbsListView.LayoutParams lp = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 64);

        TextView textView = new TextView(Form.this);
        textView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        // Center the text vertically
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.LEFT);
        // Set the text starting position
        textView.setPadding(36, 0, 0, 0);
        return textView;
    }

    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        /*TextView textView = getGenericView();
        textView.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString()+"arun");
        return textView;*/
        final Spinner spinner = new Spinner(getApplicationContext());
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, contents);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, 
            View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) 
            {
                int index = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                    "You have selected item : " + contents[index], 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}
        });

        return spinner;
    }

    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groups[groupPosition];
    }

    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groups.length;
    }

    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView textView = getGenericView();
        textView.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
        return textView;
    }

    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to implement?

```
public class SpinnerActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    ...

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
            int pos, long id) {
        // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
        // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Another interface callback
    }
}
```