# How to put ExpandableListView inside spinner in android

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am looking for `Spinner` having `ExpandablelistView` inside it. I want to click on the spinner view , it shows the `ExpandablelistView` main categories inside it, then by clicking any of the main category, the sub categories will be shown.
i found this example 
[spinner within expandable list view? in the child menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468123/spinner-within-expandable-list-view-in-the-child-menu)
i want the same `ExpandablelistView` but inside spinner view. i am new to android and are in the stage of learning. Any help will be heartly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You can open a dialog with an ExpandableListView inside, when user click in the spinner. I'm afraid is not possible to embbed the ELV inside Spinner. Another option would be custom the Spinner adapter with your views of child and group and "simulate" and ELV.

Comment: any reference example regarding your suggestion?

Comment: how can i do if i want to show the ExpandablelistView with a button or with a filterable editText

Answer (score 0):

Spinner and ExpandableListview are two independent views so you can not embedded one into the other. But I have some solution for you here:

1. Add a spinner to main layout
2. Add a ExpandableListView to main layout
3. Then On Click/Touch event of spinner you have to show the listview on spinner's bottom.

Note: Data which you want to show in spinner then you have to show it in listview.

Comment: Any Example for it as i am beginner in android